# Visual Studio выдает ошибку

Tags: c#

Visual Studio выдает ошибку Exception: System.Exception: и пишет что ошибка в 1 строке, а на первой строке у меня using System. Вот код:

```
using System;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace CSharpKernel1
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {

        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }


        protected override void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Neosart OS!");
            while (true)
            {
                string name;
                Console.Write("\n" + "A:/Neosart>");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                if (name == "calc.neo")
                {
                    int num4;
                    int num1;
                    int num2;
                    Console.Write("Введите первое число:");
                    num1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Введите второе число:");
                    num2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Введите оператор:");
                    string num3 = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (num3 == "+")
                    {
                        num4 = num1 + num2;
                        Console.Write("Ответ: " + num4);
                    }
                    else if (num3 == "-")
                    {
                        num4 = num1 - num2;
                        Console.Write("Ответ: " + num4);
                    }
                    else if (num3 == "*")
                    {
                         num4 = num1 * num2;
                         Console.Write("Ответ: " + num4);
                    }
                    else if (num3 == "/")
                    {
                        num4 = num1 / num2;
                        Console.Write("Ответ: " + num4 + "\n");
                    }
                    switch (num3)
                    {
                      case "shutdown": //Выключение компьютера
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t /f 00");
                        break;
                      case "restart": //Перезагрузка
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");
                        break;
                    }
               }

           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: а код можете показать? и что за сообщение в исключении?

Comment: Вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201155/389401

Comment: Код программы должен быть в теле вопроса, а не комментариях и, уж не тем более, - в ответе. Дабы Вы не теряли время, я перенес код, в то место, которое надо. Есть смысл согласится с моей правкой и удалить ответ с Вашим комментарием, который на него ссылается.  В вопрос нужно добавить текст EXception.

Comment: Когда вы получаете полезный на ваш взгляд ответ, его надо принять с помощью галочки, расположенной слева от ответа. Зайдите к себе в профиль, пройдитесь по всем прошлым вопросам и примите ответы, соответствующие вашим ожиданиям.

Comment: Вы пишете код в какой операционной системе? В Windows? Или Cosmos? Neosart?